# NativeScript Angular ListView Rendering [object Object]

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to play a ListView in Nativescript + Angular and I can not render the defined template. My ListView is showing [object Object] instead of the template. I always get that result. If the items in my array are a String, the text is displayed on the line, if it is an object it insists on not showing my template and displaying [object Object].

The result I get is this:

[image]

Below is my code

**eventos.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: "PrincipalEventosListView",
  templateUrl: "pages/principal/eventos/eventos.component.html",
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})

export class PrincipalEventosComponent  {

  public registros: Array<any>;

    constructor() {

        this.registros = [];
        this.registros.push({tipo: "Teste 1"});
        this.registros.push("String no lugar de objeto.");
        this.registros.push({tipo: "Teste 3"});
        this.registros.push(123);
        this.registros.push({tipo: "Teste 4"});
    }

}
```

**eventos.component.html**

```
<GridLayout>

<ListView [items]="registros">
    <template let-item="item">
        <Label [text]="item.tipo"></Label>
    </template>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You should use english for questions here...

Comment: @DawidZbiński I translated now

Comment: looking at your code this should work as expected..  see this as a reference https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/ui-category/listview/creating-listview/creating-listview.component.ts also check your package.json versions of all angular related dependencies and rebuild your app.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, I fix it by including import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform"; in the module containing the list.

Answer (score 1):

Using NativeScript 4.1.1:

You do need this in the app.module:

```
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
```

But then in the specific module referencing the ListView you need to import this:

```
import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";
```

I'm using RadListView, but I think this may apply to the normal ListView as well.

Answer (score 0):

As for now, you need import NativeScriptCommonModule from 'nativescript-angular/common' to containing module.

Answer (score -1):

In NativeScript 4.1.0 you have to include this module

```
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
```

and add it to the imports

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NativeScriptModule],
  ...
})
```